# How can I swap the 2 column names of the table without breaking the integrity in ROR?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Is it possible to somehow swap the names of the table columns without violating the integrity of the database, by migrating in ruby on rails, with the database to MySQL?

Comment: Use 3rd intermediate name.

Comment: What does "without violating the integrity of the migration" even mean? Migrations are just a DSL that creates SQL which you then run in a structured way against the DB instead of copy-pasting stuff into a database client. What is the migration in question and what the specific problem you have encounted? Are you talking about a failing constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the names with one SQL query, for me it was the best solution)

```
alter table t1 change c1 c2, change c2 c1;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use following code within model to rename or alias the column name without writing migration in Rails.

```
alias_attribute :new_column_name, :column_name_in_db
```